# Changing argument from list to character

Tags: r

I have a simple function in R I want to make that uses the `split` function as well as the `merge` function. They both take the same argument by but `split` need a factor in a list and `merge` need by as a a character string.

I just want to be able to pass the list argument to merge but I can't seem to convert the argument to characters.

I don't know if I am taking the problem the right way.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
y<-c('a','a','b','a')
df<- data.frame(x,y)

by<-df$y
data.frame.list<-split(df,by)
merge<-Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y,by=by, all=TRUE), data.frame.list)
 Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns
```

Comment: You need to show sample code with reproducible example.  You can use dput() on shortened data set to share as well.

Comment: Just convert it to the appropriate datatype before you execute split or merge:  `split(as.factor(iris$Species))` and `merge(as.character(iris$Species))`

Comment: Editted for example.